# Order jQuery functions, only run when last is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to control the order of my functions in jquery, on click id like an image to fade out, the source of the image to be swapped, and then the new image fade in.

I have the following that sort of works, only it does them all at once, is their a way to prevent this?

```
    // Animate height of div containing information
    $(this).animate({
        'height' : '600px'  
    },500, function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top });

        // Fade initial image out
        img.fadeOut();

        // Switch to hi-red image
        img.attr('src', function(i, value) {
            return '_includes/images/work/hires/' + value;
        });

        //Fade Hi res image in
        img.fadeIn();  
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with `promise()`

```
// Fade initial image out
img.fadeOut();

// Switch to hi-red image
img.promise().done(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, value) { return '_includes/images/work/hires/' + value; });
});

//Fade Hi res image in
img.fadeIn();
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Nice - I was unaware of this API. Very similar to queue, but a bit friendlier to use in this case.

Comment: You can't call regular jQuery methods on a returned promise. You need to register a callback on the promise, e.g. `.done(function() { this.attr('src', ...); this.fadeIn(); });`

Comment: Why promise and not just use the complete callback? I'm still puzzled as to why they added this.

Comment: @ErikReppen It depends really. The `complete` callback fires when the `fadeOut` is completed, whereas the promise is resolved when *all* animations are completed. In this case, they're equivalent since there's only one animation (`fadeOut`). In more complex animations where animations may still be queued later on, a promise can be used to also wait until those have completed. (Side note: the `fadeIn()` should also be inside the promise callback, otherwise the image fades back in immediately even before switching images.)

Comment: @ErikReppen Also, promises are more general than animation callbacks, jQuery exposes them for practically all asynchronous operations. For example, AJAX calls also return a promise which is resolved when the requested data is retrieved. Promises can also be combined or piped, facilitating working with asynchronously retrieved results.

Answer (score 3):

`fadeOut` can take a `complete` attribute : http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

```
// Animate height of div containing information
$(this).animate({
    'height' : '600px'  
},500, function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top });

    // Fade initial image out
    img.fadeOut(400, function() {
        // Switch to hi-red image
        img.attr('src', function(i, value) {
            return '_includes/images/work/hires/' + value;
        });

        //Fade Hi res image in
        img.fadeIn();  
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'queue' functionality of jQuery to queue up function calls.

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback function.

```
// Fade initial image out
img.fadeOut(duration, function () {
    // Switch to hi-red image
    img.attr('src', function(i, value) {
        return '_includes/images/work/hires/' + value;
    });

    //Fade Hi res image in
    img.fadeIn();
})
```

This way, once the first image had faded out, jQuery will call the anonymous function you passed as an argument.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/